# Функция exec не видит переменную php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, redbeanphp

```
$r = $userr['0'];
$t = $r['login'];
echo $t;


$usert = R::findOne('np', 'cod = ?', array($qq['nm']));

if(isset($qq['nmm'])){



     if ( $usert ){

global $r, $t;
echo $t;

        $newpass = substr(password_hash(time(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT), 0, 10);
         $passt = password_hash($newpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        R::exec("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$passt' WHERE `users` . `login` = '$t'");

echo "Ваш новый пароль: " . $newpass . "<br><a href='index.php'> Выйти на главную </a>";

    }

}



?>
```

Проблема в том, что exec не видит $t. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А как вы определили, что не видит?

Comment: Он не находит по логину. Я поставил вместо переменной значение, которое мне нужно и функция сработала. Также пытался вызвать с помощью echo не вывелась.

Comment: Напишите вот так '".$t."'"

Comment: Из вашего кода совершенно не понятно что такое `$r['login'];` Вот нигде в коде не увидел заполнения данной пременной.

Comment: Ваш код взорвался что ли?

Comment: $userr = R::getAll("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users` . `email` = '$fg'");

Comment: @u_mulder не опускайтесь так низко, не называйте это кодом )